# struct bitfield max size (C99, C++)

Tags: c++, c, struct, c99, bit-fields

What is maximal bit width for bit struct field?

```
struct i { long long i:127;}
```

Can I define a bit field inside struct, with size of bitfield up to 128 bit, or 256 bit, or larger? There are some extra-wide vector types, like sse2 (128-bit), avx1/avx2 (256-bit), avx-512 (512-bit for next Xeon Phis) registers; and also extensions like [__int128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) in gcc.

Comment: For long bit fields, you may want to investigate std::bitset declared in <bitset>.  As for bit limitations, I suggest first reading your compiler documentation for limitations as these are generally more strict than those imposed by the language standard.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, what are generic limitations of max bit field size? Does standard define some upper limit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C99 §6.7.2.1, paragraph 3:

> The expression that specifies the
>   width of a bit-field shall be an
>   integer constant expression that has
>   nonnegative value that **shall not
>   exceed the number of bits in an object
>   of the type that is specified if the
>   colon and expression are omitted**. If
>   the value is zero, the declaration
>   shall have no declarator.

C++0xa §9.6, paragraph 1:

> ... The constant-expression shall be an
>   integral constant expression with a
>   value greater than or equal to zero.
>   The value of the integral constant
>   expression may be larger than the
>   number of bits in the object
>   representation (3.9) of the
>   bit-field’s type; **in such cases the
>   extra bits are used as padding bits
>   and do not participate in the value
>   representation (3.9) of the bit-field**.

So in C you can't do that at all, and in C++ it won't do what you want it to.

Comment: You just forgot to mention that in C99 the only types that are guaranteed to work are `_Bool`, `signed int` and `unsigned int`. In particular the use by the OP of `long long` is implementation specific.

Comment: @JensGustedt is the restriction by standard also? If so, somewhere near 6.7.2.1?

Comment: @WhozCraig: That restriction is paragraph 4 of 6.7.2.1: "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type."

Comment: @JensGustedt: If the implementation supports bit-field types other than those listed, the restriction in paragraph 5 still applies. `long long i:127;` must trigger a diagnostic if the implementation doesn't support `long long` bit fields. If it does support them, then it must be diagnosed if `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (long long) < 127` (which is true for every implementation I've seen, but not mandated). This comment applies only to C, not to C++.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ Standard sets no limits on the size of a bit-field, other than that it must be greater or equal to zero - section 9.6/1. It also says:

> Bit-fields are packed into some
>   addressable allocation unit. [Note:
>   bit-fields straddle allocation units
>   on some machines and not on others.
>   Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left
>   on some machines, left-to-right on
>   others. ]

Which I suppose could be taken to indicate some sort of maximum size.

This does not mean that your specific compiler implementation supports arbitrarily sized bit-fields, of course.

Comment: @osgx I don't know - I never, ever use bit-fields in my own code, so it's not an issue for me.

Comment: @osgx: GCC supports wacky bitfield sizes. An oversized bitfield (even `char a : 10;` simply wastes the extra bits.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you cannot allocate more bits than the underlying type has.  If `long long` is 64 bits, then your bitfield is probably limited to :64.

Comment: If i will use mmx/sse2 type (128 or 256 bits), can I allocate 3/4 of it as bitfield?

Comment: These are not *integral types* as far as the compiler is concerned, so they have no bearing effect on the maximum width of a bitfield you can declare.

Answer (score 1):

Since the values of bit-fields are assigned to integers, I'd assume that the largest bit-field value you can use is that of the size of intmax_t.

Edit:

From the C99 Spec:

6.7.2.1 Bullet 9:

> A bit-field is interpreted as a signed
>   or unsigned integer type consisting of
>   the specified number of bits. If
>   the value 0 or 1 is stored into a
>   nonzero-width bit-field of type
>   _Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value
>   stored.

6.7.2.1 Bullet 10:

> An implementation may allocate any
>   addressable storage unit large enough
>   to hold a bit- field. If enough space
>   remains, a bit-field that immediately
>   follows another bit-field in a
>   structure shall be packed into
>   adjacent bits of the same unit. If
>   insufficient space remains, whether a
>   bit-field that does not fit is put into
>   the next unit or overlaps adjacent
>   units is implementation-defined. The
>   order of allocation of bit-fields
>   within a unit (high-order to low-order
>   or low-order to high-order) is
>   implementation-defined. The alignment
>   of the addressable storage unit is
>   unspecified.

Comment: sample from my question: long long i. I can use up to 64 bits of this longlong as bitfiled, which is greater than int

Comment: These quotes do not support your assumption…

Comment: What part of the spec does not support my assumption?  "A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type."  That implies that the largest bit-field size is the size of the largest integer type.  I included bullet 10, because my interpretation of that bullet is that any sized storage unit (larger than zero bits) can have a bit field.  It appears that this supports the OP's desire to add bit-fields to "extra-width vector types" as long as the bit-field sizes are smaller than intmax_t.  

If I am interpreting something wrong, please correct me.