# What is the type of a bitfield?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, bit-fields, c11

I can't find anywhere in the C standard where this is specified. For example, in

```
struct { signed int x:1; } foo;
```

is `foo.x` an lvalue of type `int`, or something else? It seems unnatural for it to be an lvalue of type `int` since you cannot store any value of type `int` in it, only 0 or -1, but I can't find any language that would assign it a different type. Of course, used in most expressions, it would get promoted to `int` anyway, but the actual type makes a difference in C11 with `_Generic`, and I can't find any language in the standard about how bitfields interact with `_Generic` either.

Comment: An interesting about bitfields is that `int` and `signed int` have different meaning in them. Dunno if this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647320/struct-bitfield-max-size-c99-c

Comment: The 'maximum size of a bit field' in question 2647320 is not directly related to this issue.

Comment: This question is NOT about the size or range of values of a bitfield. I specifically used the `signed` keyword to avoid the implementation-defined signedness issue. The question is **purely** a matter of **what type** the lvalue `foo.x` has.

Answer (score 5):

As Jonathan already cited, p5 clearly states what the type a bit-field has.

What you should have also in mind is that there is a special rule for bit-field arithmetic conversions in 6.3.1.1, basically stating that if an `int` can represent all values such a bit-field *converts* to an `int` in most expressions.

What the type would be in a `_Generic` should be the declared type (modulo the sign glitch), since it seems to be consensus that arithmetic conversions don't apply, there. So

```
_Generic((X), int: toto, unsigned: tutu)
_Generic(+(X), int: toto, unsigned: tutu)
```

could give you different results if `X` is an unsigned bit-field with a width that has all values fit into an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you included the `signed` qualifier, then the only values that can be stored in the 1-bit bit field are indeed -1 and 0.  If you'd omitted the qualifier, it would be implementation defined whether the 'plain' `int` bit field was signed or unsigned.  If you'd specified `unsigned int`, of course, the values would be 0 and +1.

The relevant sections of the standard are:

> #### §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶4 The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant
>   expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the
>   type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted.<sup>122)</sup> If the value is
>   zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.
>
> ¶5 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
>   int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is
>   implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.
>
> ¶10 A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the
>   specified number of bits.<sup>125)</sup> If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of
>   type `_Bool`, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool`
>   bit-field has the semantics of a `_Bool`.
>
> <sup>122)</sup> While the number of bits in a `_Bool` object is at least `CHAR_BIT`, the width (number of sign and
>   value bits) of a `_Bool` may be just 1 bit.
>
> <sup>125)</sup> As specified in 6.7.2 above, if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`,
>   then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned.

The footnote 125 points to:

> #### §6.7.2 Type Specifiers
>
> ¶5 Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bitfields,
>   it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as
>   `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.

Comment: I didn't ask about the range of values. I asked what type the lvalue has. This matters for how it interacts with `_Generic`, and in other obscure ways like `?:` operator weirdness.

Comment: It has type `signed int`, doesn't it — in your example.  And if you'd specified (plain) `int`, the type would be implementation defined.  But the type is the type specified in the declaration of the bit field.  `_Bool` if you specified `_Bool`, otherwise, whatever integer type you specify.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something or you're over-cerebrating (or both).

Comment: I'm just a little bit troubled by the concept that you can have an lvalue of type `int` that cannot be used to faithfully store and retrieve any value of type `int`. Conceptually, it seems like the type should be "signed bitfield of width 1" or similar, but C has no such "type", so I suppose the type of the lvalue really is `int`...

Answer (score 3):

The C11 specification certainly does not make this clear, and is perhaps deficient.

I believe that `foo.x` is an lvalue with type other than `int`, but my justification is pretty weak:

6.2.7 paragraph 1 says:

> Two types have *compatible type* if their types are the same.

6.3 paragraph 2 says:

> Conversion of an operand value to a compatible type causes no change to the value or the representation.

If `foo.x` is an lvalue of type `int`, then it would be compatible with other `int`s so `foo.x = 5` should result in `foo.x` having value `5` (per 6.3p2).  That obviously can't happen, suggesting that `foo.x` is not compatible with `int`, suggesting that `foo.x` is not an lvalue of type `int`.

It doesn't really make sense that `foo.x` isn't compatible with `int`.  Maybe no conversion (in the 6.3.1 sense) occurs, and that `foo.x` obtains its value via some mechanism not discussed in the standard.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what "arithmetic operands" means, and that 6.3.1 doesn't apply to lvalues.

There's also 6.3.1.1 paragraph 1 bullet 2, which says:

> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.

`foo.x` has less precision than an ordinary `int` (when used as an lvalue, not when it "is converted to the value stored in the designated object" as described in 6.3.2.1p2), so it must have a different integer conversion rank.  This also suggests that it is not an `int`.

But I'm not sure that my interpretation is valid or matches the intention of the committee.

I would recommend submitting a defect report about this.

Answer (score 3):

> ... the actual type makes a difference in C11 with `_Generic`

The results of how 1 compiler treats the bit field types is shown below.

The 8-bit and 32-bit fields match the usual suspects.

What is the type of a 1-bit bitfield?  As others have cited, its "name" is not clearly specified, but it is not any of the expected standard types.

This does not cite a specification, but does demonstrate how a respected compiler interpreted the C spec.

---

GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)
compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3

```
#define info_typename(X) _Generic((X), \
  _Bool: "_Bool", \
  unsigned char: "unsigned char", \
  signed char: "signed char", \
  char: "char", \
  int: "int", \
  unsigned : "unsigned", \
  default: "default" \
  )

#define TYPE_NAME(t) { printf("%s\n", info_typename(t)); }
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct {
    signed int x1 :1;
    signed int x8 :8;
    signed int x32 :32;
    _Bool b;
    signed char sc;
    char c;
    unsigned char uc;
    int i;
    unsigned u;
  } foo;
  TYPE_NAME(foo.b);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.sc);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.c);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.uc);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.i);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.u);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.x1);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.x8);
  TYPE_NAME(foo.x32);
}
```

Output

```
_Bool
signed char
char
unsigned char
int
unsigned
default           (int:1)
signed char       (int:8)
int               (int:32)
```

---

Note with `-Wconversion` and the below code, I get this warning.  So that is at least what one compiler calls its small bit field type: `unsigned char:3`.

> warning: conversion to 'unsigned char:3' from 'unsigned int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

```
  struct {
    unsigned int x3 :3;
  } foo;
  unsigned u = 1;
  foo.x3 = u; // warning
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of a bit-field is:

*bit-field of type `T`*

where `T` is either `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, `unsigned int` or some implementation-defined type.

In your example, `foo.x` is of type: bit-field of type `signed int`.

This is different than `signed int` because the two types don't share the same constraints and requirements.

For example:

```
/* foo.x is of type bit-field of type signed int */
struct { signed int x:1; } foo; 

/* y is of type signed int */
signed int y;                     

/* valid, taking the size of an expression of type signed int */
sizeof y;

/* not valid, taking the size of an expression of type bit-field
 * of signed int */
sizeof foo.x;  

/* valid, taking the address of a lvalue of type signed int */
&y;            

/* invalid, taking the address of a lvalue of type bit-field
 * of signed int */
&foo.x;
```

Comment: This is what I'd like to believe, but I can't find any language in the standard that defines such a thing as "bit-field of type T". In fact, the specification of the constraints on `&` say nothing about the *type* of the expression; they refer to the *object* which the lvalue designates, and require that it not be a bit-field.

Comment: And to be more accurate it should be something like *bit-field of type `T` and of width `n`*. In DR#120 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_120.html regarding bit-fields C Committee say about this declaration `struct S { unsigned bit:1; };` that `bit` *can be informally described as unsigned int : 1*

Answer (score 2):

The C11 Standard states in 6.7.2.1p5:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-defined type.

This is a constraint, meaning, if a program declares a bit field with a type that does not fall into one of the categories above, a diagnostic must be printed.

However it then goes on to say in 6.7.2.1p10:

> A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits.

I believe what they mean is that, while you must declare the bit field with something like `signed int x:n`, the type of the lvalue expression `foo.x` is some other signed integer type, call it T.  T is a signed integer type consisting of n bits and must comply with the constraints on all signed integer types given in Sec. 6.2.6.  But T is not necessarily compatible with the standard signed integer type named `signed int`.  (In fact, the only situation in which it is possible for T to be compatible with that standard type is if n happens to equal the number of bits in a signed int.)

Unfortunately, the Standard does not provide any means to name the type T, so I can't see how it can be used in a `_Generic`, at least, not in a portable way.  Specific implementations of the C language may provide a mechanism to name this type, but the Standard does not force them to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that this would depend on:

1. The compiler
2. Optimization settings
3. The maximum number of bits in the bit field

Comment: For the given information, there is nothing left to the compiler, the optimization settings, or the maximum number of bits in the bit field.  If the `signed` had been omitted, then it would have 'implementation defined' behaviour (so it would vary by compiler), but optimization level would not be a factor (unless the implementation defined that its behaviour depended on the optimization level, I suppose, but that's pretty unlikely), and the maximum number of bits is still not a factor.

Comment: @Jonathan You're right. I believe I was thinking it would have been analogous to the case of "what is the underlying type of an enum?"